# Variance of Random Walk with Drift

Tags: probability, asset-pricing, random-walk, proof

For Gaussian random variables $\xi_t$ with mean $\mu_t$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, consider the random walk with initial condition $P_0=100$, such that

\begin{equation}
P_t=P_{t-1}(1+\xi_t).
\end{equation}

I assume that variance of $P_t$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \text{Var}P_{t}&=\text{Var}\left(P_{0}\prod_{i=1}^{t}\left(1+\xi_{i}\right)\right),\\&=P_{0}^{2}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{t}\left(1+\xi_{i}\right)^{2}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^{t}\left(1+\xi_{i}\right)\right]^{2}\right),\\&=\mathbb{E}\left[P_{t}\right]^2\left(\left(1+\frac{\sigma^{2}}{\mathbb{E}\left[P_{t}\right]}\right)^{t}-1\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

However, I would like to know whether this can be proven for a changing mean $u_t$, such that $\mathbb{E}[P_t]\neq P_0(1+\mu)^t$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome. How do you want to approach this problem? How do you have to(?) approach this problem? I.e. could you run some simulation studies, or are approximations acceptable, e.g. assuming $1+\xi_t$ to be lognormally distributed, and $x_t=\log(1+\xi_t)$ to be normally distributed so that $P_t=P_0e^{\sum_{\tau=1}^t x_{\tau}}$ ?

Comment: You can, of course, find the variance of $Z_t=\prod_{i=1}^{t}\xi_i$ via $Var(Z_t)=E(Z_t^2)-E(Z_t)^2$ and calculating $E(Z_t^2)$ as $\left((1+\mu)^2+\sigma^2\right)^t$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Kermittfrog. Approximations are fine, though $\xi_t$ is meant to denote daily price returns (Mandelbrot proposed a Lévy alpha-stable distribution, but I have approximated with a Gaussian $\xi$). The variance of $Z_t$ is enough to determine the variance of $P_t$, so thanks again.

Comment: I have updated the question for time varying $\mu$ with my calculation of variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setup

Let

$$Z_n\equiv \prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1+x_i)$$

where each $x_i$ is iid normally distributed as  $x_i\sim \mathrm{N}\left(\tilde{\mu},\sigma\right)$. For simplicity, and with some abuse of notation, let $\mu = 1 + \tilde{\mu} $, i.e.

$$Z_n\equiv \prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1+x_i)\sim\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(\mu + \sigma\varepsilon_i)$$

where each $\varepsilon_i$ is iid standard normal, $\varepsilon_i\sim \mathrm{N}\left(0,1\right)$. Note that

$$Z_n\equiv \prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1+x_i)\sim\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(\mu + \sigma\varepsilon_i)\left(\mu+\sigma\varepsilon_n\right)=Z_{n-1}\left(\mu+\sigma\varepsilon_n\right)$$
which we will use below.

### First and second moments

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(Z_1\right)&=\mathrm{E}\left(\mu+\sigma\varepsilon_1\right)\\
&=\mu
\end{align}
$$
and then:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(Z_n\right)&=\mathrm{E}\left(Z_{n-1}\left(\mu+\sigma\varepsilon_n\right)\right)\\
&=\mu\mathrm{E}\left(Z_{n-1}\right) + \sigma\mathrm{E}\left(\varepsilon_{n}Z_{n-1}\right)\\
&=\mu\mathrm{E}\left(Z_{n-1}\right)\\
&=\mu\mathrm{E}\left(\left(\mu+\sigma\varepsilon_{n-1}\right)Z_{n-2}\right)\\
&=\ldots\\
&=\mu^{n-1}\mathrm{E}\left(Z_{1}\right)\\
&=\mu^n\\
&=\left(1 + \tilde{\mu}\right)^n
\end{align}
$$

If the mean $\tilde{\mu_t}$ is time-dependent, then
$$
\mathrm{E}\left(Z_n^2\right)=\prod\limits_{t=1}^n\left(1+\tilde{\mu_t}\right)
$$

Likewise,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(Z_1^2\right)&=\mathrm{E}\left(\left(\mu+\sigma\varepsilon_1\right)^2\right)\\
&=\mathrm{E}\left(\mu^2+2\sigma\mu\varepsilon_1+\sigma^2\varepsilon_1^2\right)\\
&=\mu^2+\sigma^2
\end{align}
$$
and then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(Z_n^2\right)&=\mathrm{E}\left(Z_{n-1}^2\left(\mu+\sigma\varepsilon_n\right)^2\right)\\
&=\mathrm{E}\left(\mu^2Z_{n-1}^2\right)+2\sigma\mathrm{E}\left(\varepsilon_nZ_{n-1}^2\right)+\sigma^2\mathrm{E}\left(\varepsilon_n^2Z_{n-1}^2\right)\\
&=\left(\mu^2+\sigma^2\right)\mathrm{E}\left(Z_{n-1}^2\right)\\
&=\left(\mu^2+\sigma^2\right)\mathrm{E}\left(\left(\mu+\sigma\varepsilon_{n-1}\right)^2Z_{n-2}^2\right)\\
&=\ldots\\
&=\left(\mu^2+\sigma^2\right)^{n-1}\mathrm{E}\left(Z_{1}^2\right)\\
&=\left(\mu^2+\sigma^2\right)^{n}\\
&=\left(\left(1+\tilde{\mu}\right)^2+\sigma^2\right)^{n}
\end{align}
$$

If the mean $\tilde{\mu_t}$ is time-dependent, then
$$
\mathrm{E}\left(Z_n^2\right)=\prod\limits_{t=1}^n\left(\left(1+\tilde{\mu_t}\right)^2+\sigma^2\right)
$$

### Variance

Finally,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}\left(Z_n\right)&=\mathrm{E}\left(Z_n^2\right)-\mathrm{E}\left(Z_n\right)^2\\
&=\left(\left(1+\tilde{\mu}\right)^2+\sigma^2\right)^{n}-\left(1 + \tilde{\mu}\right)^{2n}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The mean $\mu_t$ (your $\tilde{\mu}$) varies with time. So, the random variables are independent but not identically distributed. I was wondering if a solution could be found for varying $\mu_t$ in terms of $\mathbb{E}[P_t]$. Nonetheless, your response is very helpful for constant $\mu$ (i.i.d random variables).

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sure, thanks again.